# How to add/remove a fieldset when click on button

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm programming in Angular2/Typescript and for the add form, I need to add the possibility to add/remove a fieldset in which the input are linked to a ViewModel. So basically, I have a principal ViewModel which comprises a table of the secondary ViewModel (fieldset). I tried different things, but I'm new in Angular so I'm probably missing important things.

Here is the code of my HTML code :

```html
<div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <label>Customer : </label>
                    <select class="form-control" required ngControl="viewModel.selectedCustomerStr"
                            [(ngModel)]="viewModel.selectedCustomerStr">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option *ngFor="#customer of viewModel.customersListStr" [value]="customer">{{customer}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Service provided: </label>
                    <select class="form-control" required ngControl="viewModel.serviceProvidedStr"
                            [(ngModel)]="viewModel.serviceProvidedStr">
                        <option value=null></option>
                        <option *ngFor="#service of viewModel.servicesListStr" [value]="service">{{service}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <label>Service window : </label>
                    <select class="form-control" required ngControl="viewModel.selectedServiceWindowStr"
                        [(ngModel)]="viewModel.selectedServiceWindowStr">
                        <option value=null></option>
                        <option *ngFor="#window of serviceWindowListStr" [value]="window">{{window}}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <fieldset *ngFor="#choice of choices">
                    <legend>DRP contact information</legend>
                    <div>
                        <label>DRP contact name:</label>
                        <input placeholder="Contact's Name" type="text" maxlenght=50 [(ngModel)]="viewModel.contactName"
                            class="form-control" required ngControl="name" #name="ngForm">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>Start time:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" ngControl="timeStart" required type="time"
                           [(ngModel)]="viewModel.timeStart">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>End time:</label>
                        <input class="form-control" ngControl="timeEnd" required type="time"
                           [(ngModel)]="viewModel.timeEnd">
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>Medium:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="viewModel.selectedMediumStr" ngControl="viewModel.selectedMediumStr"
                            #medium="ngForm">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        <option *ngFor="#medium of viewModel.mediumsListStr" [value]="medium">{{medium}}</option>
                    </select>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label>DRP contact address:</label>
                        <input placeholder="Contact's address" type="text" maxlenght=100 [(ngModel)]="viewModel.value"
                            class="form-control" required ngControl="value" #value="ngForm">
                    </div>

                    <button class="remove" (click)="onRemoveFieldset()">Remove</button>
                </fieldset>

                <button class="add" (click)="onAddFieldset()">Add a contact</button>                  
            </div>
```

Do I need to change the ngModel for every input in the fieldset to match the table cell ?

Next is the Typescript code :

```js
export class AddDrpsComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
    viewModel:DrpDetailViewModel = new DrpDetailViewModel();
    tabDrpContact:DrpContactDetailViewModel[];
    serviceWindowListStr:String[];

    onAddFieldset() {
        let newItemNo = this.tabDrpContact.length +1;
        this.tabDrpContact.push(new DrpContactDetailViewModel(newItemNo));
    }

    onRemoveFieldset(id:number) {
        this.tabDrpContact.splice(id,1);
    }
}
```

For the moment, it's just a basic add and remove who do nothing behind.

[Picture of the add form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZbtN.png)

I hope to have been clear, English is not my mother tongue.

Cordially,

Florian

Edit : Up

EDIT 2 : Here is my two ViewModel

```js
import {DrpContact} from "./drp-contact";

export interface Drp {
    id:number;
    serviceWindow:string;
    status:string;
    customer:string;
    serviceProvidedType:string;
    drpContactList:DrpContact[];
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////

```
export interface DrpContact {
    id:number;
    name:string;
    timeStart:string;
    timeEnd:string;
    value:string;
    mediumType:string;
}
```

```js
import {SelectOptionElement} from "../../shared/model/select-option-element";
import {Serializable} from "../../shared/technical/serializable";
import {DrpContactDetailViewModel} from "./drp-contact-detail-view-model";

export class DrpDetailViewModel extends Serializable {
    id:number;

    selectedCustomer:SelectOptionElement;
    selectedCustomerStr:string;
    serviceProvided:SelectOptionElement;
    serviceProvidedStr:string;
    selectedServiceWindow:SelectOptionElement;
    selectedServiceWindowStr:string;
    status:string;
    drpContactDetailList:DrpContactDetailViewModel[];

    customer:SelectOptionElement[];
    customersListStr:String[];
    service:SelectOptionElement[];
    servicesListStr:String[];
    window:SelectOptionElement[];
}

/////////////////////


import {SelectOptionElement} from "../../shared/model/select-option-element";
import {Serializable} from "../../shared/technical/serializable";

export class DrpContactDetailViewModel extends Serializable {
    id:number;
    contactName:string;
    timeStart:string;
    timeEnd:string;
    selectedMedium:SelectOptionElement;
    selectedMediumStr:string;
    value:string;

    medium:SelectOptionElement[];
    mediumsListStr:String[];
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with what you're doing ?

Comment: For the moment, onAddFieldset and onRemoveFieldset don't work like I would like they do. Right now, they just add a fieldset at the end of a table, and when i create (for example) 5 fieldsets, if I delete the second, it will just delete the last one in the tab, not the second. Don't know if I explain it well.

Comment: What I would like is that when I click on Add, it create a new fieldset and behind it implement the table of ViewModel (tabDrpContact).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `ngFor`'s index to remove the correct `fieldset` :

In your template :

```
<fieldset *ngFor="#choice of choices; let id = index">
  //Code ...
  <button class="remove" (click)="onRemoveFieldset(id)">Remove</button>
</fieldset>
```

In your component :

```
onAddFieldset() {
    let newItemNo = this.choices.length +1;
    this.choices.push(new DrpDetailViewModel(newItemNo));
}

onRemoveFieldset(id:number) {
    this.choices.splice(id,1);
}
```

This assumes you have a constructor that matches `DrpDetailViewModel(id)`

```
class DrpContactDetailViewModel extends Serializable {
  id:number;
  contactName:string;
  timeStart:string;
  timeEnd:string;
  selectedMedium:SelectOptionElement;
  selectedMediumStr:string;
  value:string;

  medium:SelectOptionElement[];
  mediumsListStr:String[];

  constructor(id : number) { this.id = id }
}
```

Comment: I will try, I come back to you after ;)

Comment: I have add my two ViewModel, like that you can have a better view of what I want.

Comment: So `DrpDetailViewModel` implements `Drp` ?

Comment: DrpDetailViewModel = Drp, it's the same ViewModel, with some differences (for the select essentially). I have the same for DrpContact (DrpContactDetailViewModel). I use these "detail" ViewModel for the action of adding, editing.

Comment: Here, I added the "detail" ViewModel

Comment: I added the constructor that you should have, does that answer the question ?

Comment: I edited the Typescript class to match with your comments, I just get one error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at AddDrpsComponent.onAddFieldset. Probably because I don't instanciate the table ?

Comment: I guess you mean `array` by `table`, but yes you should give it a default value. `choices : any[] = []`

Comment: Yup ! I have some changes to make but it will work ! Thanks man !